# Is there a Gradle License Plugin or What is the best way to handle Licenses of Dependencies?

Tags: licensing, gradle

I'm about to release a little hobby open source project. Since it bundles a bunch of dependencies I have to take care of the various license requirements. Most of the time this means adding some license file to the distribution (at least that is my understanding, but you never know about lawyers).

Is there a Gradle plugin that takes care of that, at least for the common Open Source Licenses?

If there is no Gradle plugin, is there an accepted approach to handle this, like listing all the jars + the license after the own license, or putting a *.license file next to each *.jar file or something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a [Gradle License Plugin](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin) on Github (I'm the maintainer). Currently the plugin only adds and removes License headers to your source files. There is no support yet for adding the licenses of jar dependencies to a LICENSE file, but that shouldn't be too hard to add, just haven't had the time yet.

Comment: If you add that feature I can almost promise to try it.

Comment: Open an issue there, I'll see what I can do :-)

Comment: done: https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin/issues/12

Comment: @HieryNomus Does your plugin have support for multi-module projects? If so, can you point me to some document that describes what to do?